# sort( $new, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE ) in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, sorting

```
sort( $new, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE );
```

SORT_NATURAL is new in php 5.4 but i have 5.3.10 running on my localhost (ubuntu 12.04) not really intention to upgrade because of that.

What would be the equivalent in php 5.3, i have read that is just like natsort.

is `natsort( $new, SORT_FLAG_CASE );` the same ?

Comment: 5.4 is the up-to-date version of PHP. You should upgrade.

Comment: `natsort` doesn't take flags, but it appears there's also a `natcasesort` which is case-insensitive, would would lead me to believe that `natsort` is case-*sensitive*. So I think you want `natcasesort($new)`.

Comment: natsort() does not support extra arguments. you cannot pass any flags to it, so no... it's not equivalent: http://php.net/nat_sort

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/sort) points out that `natsort ($array)` is the equivalent of `sort($array,SORT_NATURAL);` it also points that `SORT_FLAG_CASE` wasn't added until 5.4.0 either.

You can  use [`natcasesort($array)`](http://php.net/natcasesort) which is the equivalent of `sort($array,SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE)`.

Answer (score 2):

While they are essentially the same, the important difference to note between `natsort($array)` and `sort($array, SORT_NATURAL)` is key associations.

`natsort()` maintains key associations, meaning that keys and values are kept linked.

However, `sort()` does NOT main associations, so values are reassigned keys based on their new order.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in how they work with associative arrays.

```php
$kids = [
    'john' => '10 years',
    'mary' => '2 years',
    'ivan' => '20 years', 
];
```

The `sort` will re-index elements:

```php
sort($kids, SORT_NATURAL);
var_dump($kids);

/*
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "2 years"
        [1]=>
        string(8) "10 years"
        [2]=>
        string(8) "20 years"
    }
*/
```

The `natsort` will preserve keys:

```php
natsort($kids);
var_dump($kids);

/*
    array(3) {
        ["mary"]=>
        string(7) "2 years"
        ["john"]=>
        string(8) "10 years"
        ["ivan"]=>
        string(8) "20 years"
    }
*/
```